# Fingerprint device not detected Ubuntu 20.04.1 on HP Spectre x360 13 (late 2019)

Tags: drivers, usb, 20.04, hp, fingerprint-reader

I recently installed ubuntu on my HP Spectre laptop (model in title). I wanted to enable fingerprint login which was advertised to be available upon instillation. However there is no option to add support for such a option:

[not allowed to embed images i guess](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOweW.png.)

I then tried checking to see if the system detected any fingerprint device wit `lsusb`

It was unable to locate any:

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 06cb:00c9 Synaptics, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0408:5440 Quanta Computer, Inc. HP True Vision HD Camera
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 8087:0026 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Does anyone have any advice or experience on how to get this working? I have been having a lot of trouble finding anything

Answer (score 2):

There's a [thread](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Hardware-and-Upgrade-Questions/Linux-driver-for-fingerprint-reader/m-p/6671531#M454727)! on the HP forum that has an comment with a script that can show you if it is a acpi device. I'm searching for a FP solution for my HP Envy x360 but haven't found one yet. From what I've read so far, it sounds like there may not be a solution for using the FP scanner on Linux yet.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.